# Objects lost in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a RPG-style program, but I have trouble to get my array of treasure objects to work. I want to save all treasures I find in the array, to be printed out later. Here is the code for the treasure class:

```
private static int x = 0;
Treasure treasureArray[] = new Treasure[20];

public void collectedTreasures(Treasure t){
treasureArray[x] = t;
x++;
}
```

And in the main program:

```
GoldTreasure t = new Coin();
hero1.setPoints(t.getCoin());
t.collectedTreasures(t);
```

The creation of the treasure object is within a switch within a infinite loop.
When i print out the array, with method

```
public void printTreasures(){
        for (int y=0 ; y<x ; y++){
            System.out.print(treasureArray[y] + ", ");
```

I only get "null" for as many treasures there should be in the array. If i print out the array after t.collectedTreasures(t), I see that only the last treasure is there, and the indexes before that object is null. What have I done wrong?

Yes I'm a newbie. Be nice.

Comment: your variable `x` probably shouldn't be `static`. Also consider dynamic lists like `Vector`.

Comment: Is `treasureArray[]` defined in class `Treasure`?  You probably have a separate treasure collection associated with each `Treasure` object.

Comment: `t.collectedTreasures(t);` looks suspicious to me. I haven't really spent much time looking at your code, but you're really adding itself?

Comment: @Sirko `Vector` is outdated, use `ArrayList` instead. And in this case it would probably be best to use a set.

Answer (score 6):

This code is quite suspicious:

```
GoldTreasure t = new Coin();
hero1.setPoints(t.getCoin());
t.collectedTreasures(t);
```

It means you are:

1. creating a new treasure `t`;
2. calling `collectedTreasures` on that very instance.

You should assign the treasure array to the hero, not to the treasure itself.

Also note that `x` should not be a static variable because it will get shared among all instances; clearly not your intention, since the treasure array is per-instance.

Comment: OP will be back eventually with their first ever race condition :)

Comment: True. Static just makes it easier to refer to it in places where you shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you!!! Works like a charm now with the array in the hero class instead. And no need for static x either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you collect the treasure in itself because you call the collect function - that belongs to a treasure - to collect itself.

Later on, when you call printTreasures in what object does it run? Do you create a new instance of treasure and ask for it to print what it has collected? If such, the results are according to the code and there is no issue with it, but the logic is faulty.

What you should do: the hero is the one collecting the treasures, therefore move the definition of the array of treasures, the counter and the 2 functions - collectedTreasures and printTreasures - in the hero class. Further more, make X not static, as its value will be shared among heroes. Maybe, even more ellegant, create an additional class to handle the treasures and compose you hero using different classes.

And may I suggest a renamig for the collectedTreasures(Treasure t) function to collectTreasure(Treasure t).

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your full code to give you a detailed answer, but I suspect what you are doing is creating lots of `Treasure` subclasses and calling `collectedTreasure` on each one. This is going to increment your global `x` counter each time, whereas each individual `treasureArray` only has one entry in it.

You can move the `collectedTreasure` method to the class corresponding to your `hero1` object, at the same time, get rid of the static (global) `x` variable and replace your array of `Treasure` objects with a `List` implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`), they all keep track of their own sizes so you don't have to. Plus your code won't crash when you get more than 20 treasures!